# Cannot find Yubikey devices using python-yubico library on Windows 10

Tags: python, libusb, yubico, yubikey

I'm looking to integrate 2FA into a Python app using the [python-yubico](https://github.com/Yubico/python-yubico) library. To that end, I'm trying to run the following example they've given:

```
import sys
import yubico


try:
    yk = yubico.find_yubikey(debug=False)
    print(yk.version())
except yubico.yubico_exception.YubicoError as e:
    print(e.reason)
    sys.exit(1)
```

The above code results in `usb.core.NoBackendError: No backend available` - apparently this is a known issue with Windows caused by `libusb` being unavailable.

Some digging led me to download the `libusb` binaries from https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/tag/v1.0.26

Once I had `libusb`, I moved `libusb-1.0.dll` into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` *and* `C:\Windows\system32` (just to cover my bases) and tried the following solution I found from the `pyusb` GitHub page to set the USB backend explicitly:

```
import sys
import usb.backend.libusb1
import yubico


# set the backend used by pyusb
LIBUSB_DLL = r'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\libusb-1.0.dll'
usb.backend.libusb1.get_backend(lambda _: LIBUSB_DLL)

try:
    yk = yubico.find_yubikey(debug=False)
    print(yk.version())
except yubico.yubico_exception.YubicoError as e:
    print(e.reason)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Setting the DLL path to use `SysWOW64` as above results in `No YubiKey found`, even if my YubiKey is plugged in

And, FWIW, using `system32` in the DLL path instead results in the same `No Backend Available` error.

Obviously there's something I'm missing here. I've at the very least gotten past the "backend" issue, but I still can't get `python-yubico` to find my connected device(s). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This may not help you, at all or have anything to do with your issue but, this reminds me of a problem I had with VLC. The problem was, my python was 64 bit and my VLC was not. I see you popping between these 2, and this is my first thought when reading this. Hopefully this is helpful. In short: maybe the .dll is 32 bit, but your python version is not.